# Libreoffice writer - keyboard only use

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice

Is there a cheat sheet out there, which shows how to use Libreoffice (Writer) effectively by using less mouse? Especially I'm not searching for hotkeys, but for "movement keys":

- how do I get out of a comment (STRG+ALT+C) back to the normal text?
- moving numerations (probably I got most of that)
- things I didn't think off in the moment :)

Any ideas?

Edit: No answers in the [official guides](http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/documentation/) and this [cheat sheet](https://de.scribd.com/doc/11307469/Writer-Keyboard-Shortcuts-Cheatsheet)